# Getting interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT when debuging Tensorboard with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, tensorboard

I'm trying to debug Tensor Board but I'm unable to start TB with PyCharm and I get "interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT". If I start Tensor Board over terminal and try to attach to process, it times out. When running from PyCharm I try to run from /bazel-bin/tensorboard.

Are there some additional setup steps to get Tensor Board to run with pycharm? Do I need to provide a particular build flag with Bazel?